# Creating styled-component for component but don't know type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using the styled-components library, and am trying to style a component, but I don't know the type. I've tried a bunch but I keep getting an error `Error: Cannot create styled-component for component`. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
export const StyledSupply = styled.text `
  textAlign: "center",
  fontSize: 30,
  fontWeight: "bold",
  color: "var(--accent-text)"
`;

<s.TextTitle style={StyledSupply}>
    {data.totalSupply} / {CONFIG.MAX_SUPPLY}
</s.TextTitle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at examples from the documentation: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#getting-started

If you just want to style some text, you could try changing your code to something like this:

```
// Styled Component
export const StyledSupply = styled.span`
  textAlign: center;
  fontSize: 30;
  fontWeight: bold;
  color: var(--accent-text);
`;

// Render
<StyledSupply>
    {data.totalSupply} / {CONFIG.MAX_SUPPLY}
</StyledSupply>
```

You might need to define `--accent-text` as a variable and use it instead.

Additionally, your CSS properties may need to be use the official names, e.g. `textAlign` might need to be `text-align`, etc.

You can this a step further if `s.TextTitle` is a valid component and accepts `className` as a prop, you can do this:

```
// Styled Component
export const StyledTextTitle = styled(s.TextTitle)`
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--accent-text);
`;

// Render
<StyledTextTitle>
    {data.totalSupply} / {CONFIG.MAX_SUPPLY}
</StyledTextTitle>
```

Docs: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component